# How can the inverse of an operator between Hilbert spaces H,K be defined on the dual of H?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I need some help to understand the following statement.

Let $A$ be an operator defined as follows:
$Av = -\Delta v - \nabla \text{div} u$

It is known that the operator $A$ is positive self-adjoint operator from $H^2(\Omega) \bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$ onto $L^2(\Omega)$

Then, the author considers $A^{-1}u$ for $u\in H$, where $H$ is the dual space of the $H^2(\Omega) \bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$.

But, this makes no sense to me. Doesn't $A^{-1}$ map from $L^2$ into $H^2(\Omega)\bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$?

So, the domain of $A^{-1}$ is $L^2$, but using $L^2$ as a pivot space, I know that $L^2\subset H$, so how can one apply $A^{-1}$ to any member of $H$?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the operator $A$ is positive self-adjoint operator from $H^2(\Omega) \bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$ onto $L^2(\Omega)$

This is confusing because by definition, a self-adjoint operator maps a Hilbert space (or its dense subspace) to the same Hilbert space. I'd say that $A$ is "formally self-adjoint" meaning that $\int (Af)g = \int f(Ag)$ for test functions $f,g$.

The adjoint of $A$ maps the dual of $L^2(\Omega)$ to the dual of $H^2(\Omega) \bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$. Hence, the inverse of this adjoint maps the dual of $H^2(\Omega) \bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$ to the dual of $L^2(\Omega)$. Perhaps the author decided to be sloppy and use notation $A^{-1}$ for the inverse of the adjoint of $A$ (after all, $A$ is kind of self-adjoint).

Comment: So, I suppose that the reason for your saying "formally self-adjoint" is because $H^2(\Omega)\bigcap H^1_0(\Omega)$ is not dense in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. And it's dense. To be self-adjoint, $A$ must be equal to its adjoint. Equality means, in particular, **having the same domain**.

Comment: I get it. And is it legitimate to say that the adjoint of $A$ in fact maps $L^2(\Omega)$ into $H^2(\Omega)\bigcap H^1_0(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$ since these spaces are hilbert spaces, hence self dual?

Comment: "Self-dual" is more sloppiness, often leading to more confusion. A Hilbert space is _isomorphic_ to its dual. This isomorphism may or _may not_ be useful. There are situations where you do not want to use this isomorphism, and dealing with Sobolev spaces is such a situation. [it is misguided to too-automatically identify a Hilbert space and its dual](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/314124).